# How can I use an object as initializer for custom hooks without adding complexity/state or inviting future problems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I just started using hooks in react and am creating a prototype custom hook for a framework.
The hook should take an object as an argument for initialization and cleanup (setting up/removing callbacks for example).

Here is my simplified Code so far:

```
export function useManager(InitObj) {
  const [manager] = useState(() => new Manager());

  useEffect(() => {
    manager.addRefs(InitObj)
    return () => manager.removeRefs(InitObj)
  }, [manager]);

  return manager;
}
```

to be used like this:

```
    useManager({ cb1: setData1, cb2: setData2... })
```

In future Iterations the Manager might be a shared instance, so I need to be able to be specific about what I remove upon cleanup.

I put console.log all over the place to see If i correctly understand which code will be run during a render call. From what I can tell this code does 100% what I expeted it to do!

Unfortunately (and understandably) I get a warning because I did not include InitObj in the effects dependencies. But since I get an object literal simply putting it in there will cause the effect to be cleaned up/rerun on every render call since `{} != {}` which would be completely unnecessary.

My research so far only revealed blog posts like [this one](https://blog.logrocket.com/simplifying-state-initializers-with-react-hooks/), but here only primitive data is used that is easily classified as "the same" (`1 == 1`)

So far I have found 3 possible solutions that I am not completely happy with:

1. using useMemo to memoize the object literal outside the hook

```
useManager(useMemo(() => { cb: setData }, []))
```

This adds more responsibility on the developer using my code => not desirable!

2. using useState inside the hook

```
const [iniOBj] = useState(InitObj);
```

A lot better already, but it adds state that does not feel like state. And it costs (minimal) execution time and memory, I would like to avoid that if possible.

3. using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Works for sure, but there might still be other dependencies that might be missed if I simply deactivate the warning.

So my question is:

**How can I use an object as initializer for custom hooks without adding complexity/state or inviting future problems?**

I half expect that the useState option will be my best choice, but since I am new to hooks there might still be something that eluded my understanding so far.